# libavg custom event handler

Tags: python, embedded, raspberry-pi, libavg

I'm trying to find a way to use libavg's event handlers from an embedded serial output. My understanding is that I need to create my own Publisher that I will call when I process serial commands. All I need is a way to create 10 different triggers given different serial inputs. An analogy of what I am trying to do would be to use libavg's keyboard handling to process different keyboard inputs.

I want the custom publisher to take the 10 serial outputs and pass a event.serialid parameter to various subscribers similarly to what event.keystring does.

Here is some nonfunctional code that I have that I think has the basics of what needs to be done.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from libavg import avg, statemachine, player

class Test():
    PRESSED = avg.Publisher.genMessageID()
    RELEASED = avg.Publisher.genMessageID()
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        self.registerInstance(self, parent)
        self.publish(self.PRESSED)
        self.publish(self.RELEASED)
    def isActive(self):
        self.notifySubscribers(Test.PRESSED, [])
    def isInactive(self):
        self.notifySubscribers(Test.RELEASED, [])


def onKeyDown(event):
    global node
    if event.serialid == '1':
        #serialid isn't implemented anywhere but this is what ideally I would like to have happen
        node.color = "FF8000"

def onKeyUp(event):
    global node
    node.color = "FFFFFF" 




player = avg.Player.get()

canvas = player.createMainCanvas(size=(640,480))
rootNode = player.getRootNode()
node = avg.WordsNode(pos=(10,10), font="arial", text="Hello World", parent=rootNode)
vbutton=Test()

node.subscribe(vbutton.PRESSED, onKeyDown)
node.subscribe(vbutton.RELEASED, onKeyUp)


player.play()
```

examples of custom publishers from [here](https://github.com/pararthshah/libavg-vaapi/blob/master/src/python/ui/button.py):

```
class _ButtonBase(avg.DivNode):

    PRESSED = avg.Publisher.genMessageID()
    RELEASED = avg.Publisher.genMessageID()

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(_ButtonBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.registerInstance(self, parent)
        self.publish(self.PRESSED)
        self.publish(self.RELEASED)

    def _setActiveArea(self, upNode, activeAreaNode, fatFingerEnlarge):
        self.__activeAreaNode = activeAreaNode

        if fatFingerEnlarge:
            if self.__activeAreaNode != None:
                raise(RuntimeError(
                    "Button: Can't specify both fatFingerEnlarge and activeAreaNode"))
            size = upNode.size
            minSize = 20*player.getPixelsPerMM()
            size = avg.Point2D(max(minSize, size.x), max(minSize, size.y))
            self.__activeAreaNode = avg.RectNode(size=size, opacity=0, parent=self)
        else:
            if self.__activeAreaNode == None:
                self.__activeAreaNode = self
            else:
                self.appendChild(self.__activeAreaNode)

        self._tapRecognizer = gesture.TapRecognizer(self.__activeAreaNode,
                possibleHandler=self._onDown, 
                detectedHandler=self._onTap, 
                failHandler=self._onTapFail)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary parameters through the publish-subscribe interface. The parameter(s) are passed as a list:

```
self.notifySubscribers(Test.PRESSED, [serialID])
```

And in the handler:

```
def onKeyDown(serialID):
    global node
    if serialid == '1':
        node.color = "FF8000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just had a chance to test it. Now, I'm having trouble constructing the Test publisher class. Is there any documentation on how to write it? self.registerInstance returns "Test instance has no attribute 'registerInstance'" and the same happens with self.publish.

Comment: You need to derive from Publisher.